# Как сделать прокрутку до определенного места js

Tags: javascript

как сделать если я нажимаю на шапке на кнопку меня проскролило до определенного контента на этой же странице

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант воспользоваться Element.ScrollIntoView().

Данный метод поддерживается всеми современными браузерами: IE, Firefox, Safari, Opera и Сhrome. Исколючением является Opera Mini (но кому она нужна). Еще важная делать — не все браузера могут использовать плавную прокрутку до элементов. Запомните это.

**Как пользоваться**

Допустим у нас есть элемент с id «el». Тогда наш код будет примерно таким:

```
const el = document.getElementById('el');
el.scrollIntoView();
```

В вышеуказанном примере страница прокрутиться до верхней границы элемента. Если нам нужно, чтобы прокрутилось до нижней то нам нужно передать false в метод.

```
const el = document.getElementById('el');
el.scrollIntoView(); // Прокрутка до верхней границы
el.scrollIntoView(false); // Прокрутка до нижней границы
```

Бывают и другие нужды, например если нам нужно прокрутить страницу так, чтобы блок оказался в центре. И тут нужно сказать, что функция scrollIntoView() может принимать разные параметры:

```
element.scrollIntoView(alignToTop); // Булевые параметры true или false
element.scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions); // Объект с параметрами
```

В объекте могут быть разные параметры:

**block** — определяет вертикальное выравнивание. Доступные значения: start, center,end и nearest (ближайший). По умолчанию center

**inline** — определяет горизонтальное выравнивание. Актуально если есть карусель элементов или другой горизонтальный скроллинг. Доступные значения: start, center,end и nearest (ближайший). По умолчанию nearest

**behavior** — определяет анимацию перехода. Значение одно из двух. auto и smooth(плавное). По умолчанию auto
Теперь мы знаем какие параметры в объекте может принимать метод.

**Прокрутка до центра элемента**

И вот нам понадобилось прокрутить до определённого элемента, а именно до его середины, причем как по вертикали так и по горизонтали:

```
const el = document.getElementById('el');
el.scrollIntoView({block: "center", inline: "center"}); // Задаём параметр block для вертикальной прокрутки до центра, inline до горизонтальной
```

**Плавная прокрутка**

За анимацию прокрутки отвечает параметр behavior. Для того, чтобы плавно прокрутить до центра элемета по вертикали нам нужно только задать наш парамерт, а block и так по умолчанию center.

```
const el = document.getElementById('el');
el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```